# getch() of ncurses doesn't work

Tags: linux, key, ncurses, getch

I need to create a mainloop for my program and wrote the following function:

```
void menu(){
int ch;
cbreak();
noecho();
initscr();
refresh();
while (ch != KEY_F(9)){
    ch = getch();
    cout << ch << endl;
    switch (ch){
        case KEY_F(1): add();
            break;

        case KEY_F(2): edit();
            break;

        case KEY_F(3):
            break;

        case KEY_F(4):
            break;


    }

}

endwin();
```

}

But getch() doesn't work and print -1 in loop. how i do? 
May i set special attr or call special func?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `keypad()` e.g. `keypad(stdscr, TRUE)`.  But beyond that the function keys may not work on your terminal.  Check your ncurses.h file for a [has_key()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getch) function and you can use that to determine if they are available on your terminal.

Comment: The calls to cbreak() and noecho() should also be after the call to initscr().

Comment: I solved it, after initscr() i should call cbreak and then keypad() then getch() work correctly.thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, every ncurses function should be used only after `initscr()` has been called. In your code `cbreak()` and `noecho()` are probably ignored.
Second, if you want to use [function keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_key), you have to tell that to ncurses, by calling `keypad(stdscr, TRUE)`. However, since not every computer has got function keys, you should always check if the system support that functionality, using `has_key()` (same for `has_colors()` that checks if current terminal supports colors).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, my loop is here:

```
initscr();
clear();
noecho();
cbreak();   /* Line buffering disabled. pass on everything */
startx = (80 - WIDTH) / 2;
starty = (24 - HEIGHT) / 2;


menu_win = newwin(HEIGHT, WIDTH, starty, startx);
keypad(menu_win, TRUE);
mvprintw(0, 0, "Name of my program");
refresh();
print_menu(menu_win, highlight);
while (true)

    {   c = wgetch(menu_win);
        switch(c){
TYPE OF KEYS;
}//END OF SWITCH
}//END OF LOOP
```